# Delay in reading TCP socket data

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to continuously read count of data byte on tcp socket using `inputStream.available()`.If it return value greater than 0 then reading data from TCP using `inputStream.read(byte[inputstream.available()] b)`. But It only return the count if we received data with [PSH,ACK] (in Wireshark). When there is Only data having [ACK] (in wireshark) it's returning 0 every time till data with [PSH,ACK] is not received. It occurs only when there is huge amount of data need to be send by the server(Do not have idea about server Implementation).

Here is the code snippet :

```
while(inputStream.available()>0){
    byte [] bytesFromServer=new byte[inputStream.available()]
    inputStream.read(bytesFromServer);
}
```

The problem is :-
1. Can I read the data without worrying about [PSH,ACK] or [ACK] flag in the data.
2. Why is data taking time having [PSH,ACK] flag from the server.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to continuously read tcp socket using `inputStream.available().`

This is your first mistake. `InputStream.available()` doesn't read data: it only provides an *estimate* of how much data is available to be read without blocking. If you're trying to read continuously, you don't need `available()` at all. Just call one of the `read()` methods, preferably one that takes a (large) byte array.

> It only return the count if we received data with [PSH,ACK] (in Wireshark). When there is Only data having [ACK] (in wireshark) it's returning 0 every time till data with [PSH,ACK] is not received. It occurs only when there is huge amount of data need to be send by the server(Do not have idea about server Implementation).

It doesn't matter what `available()` returns. It's surprising to hear that your platform actually implements the PSH flag, but regardless of that you should just block in `read()`. No point in any other strategy.

> The problem is:
>   1. Can I read the data without worrying about [PSH,ACK] or [ACK] flag in the data.

Yes.

> 2. Why is data taking time having [PSH,ACK] flag from the server.

No idea but it's irrelevant.

```
while(inputStream.available()>0){
    byte [] bytesFromServer=new byte[inputStream.available()]
    inputStream.read(bytesFromServer);
}
```

As well as two system calls per read, this code drives a garbage-collection frenzy and doesn't read to end of stream. Try this:

```
byte [] bytesFromServer=new byte[8192]; // or double or quadruple if you like
int count;
while ((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    // do something with buffer[0..count-1]
}
```

Comment: I think, inputStream.available() will read TCP socket and retrun the number of byte available on the on the socket available to read. Here I am trying to continuously read the number of byte available using this method is data/or number of byte is greater than 0 than only I am trying to read the data using read() or read(byte[inputstream.available()]).

Comment: I am new for TCP network. My observation is when  data having [PSH,ACK] comes to the socket only then in java .available method is going to return the count otherwise it will return 0 only. So If the available() count is zero I am not going to read the data as I don't have Idea about size of Byte that need to read.

Comment: `InputStream.available()` will return an *estimate* of the number of bytes available to be read without blocking. See the Javadoc. It is an extra system call. Knowing it is of no use. You still have to do the read, which is another system call, and `read()` returns a count, which is all you managed to get out of `available()`, so why double the number of system calls? You don't need to know the number of bytes to read: just use a buffer that's big enough.

Comment: I have tried with read(byte[] bytes) still the delay is there . I thought i will read the data before receiving flag [PSH,ACK]

My observation is :-
Java is only able to read the data from TCP after getting flag [PSH,ACK], Function will wait until it get the packet having this flag.

Comment: @Amityadav That's not Java, that's the platform. Nothing anybody can do about it except ensure the sender sets the PSH flag. What's the client platform?